# SingleStore MEMSQL Listing all Tabular content data along with column names sequentially

Tags: sql, singlestore

Have 100+ columns in `Departments` Table in SingleStore MemSQL DB. Looking Best way to show Table contents/data based on Name, Age, City... in ascending sorted order along with columns also in ascending sorted order.

Below query returning Error:

```
Select (SELECT  
COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME ='Departments'
    ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME ASC) from Departments order by Name, Age, City asc;
```

> Error: SQL Error [1749] [HY000]: (conn=8400172) MemSQL doesn't support
> querying an information_schema table along with a user table in
> distributed.

Comment: How are MySQL and Postgresql related to this? And regex?

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: Sql is not a dynamic programming language. You cannot use an inner query to populate the select list or table definition of an outer query. You need to run the inner query first and dynamically construct the query with column names in a certain order.